# Mysql select trouble

Tags: mysql, regex, select, sql-like

It's the first time that I'm trying to achieve this kind of select.

I have a column on my table that stores values like `1,3,45,32,47,4,9,100,23,2`

I want to make a `select` and retrieve just the values that match for example `4` but `not 45` on all lines of table.

some times this column just have one number like `4`

if i make a selection using `LIKE %4,%` the SQL only will retrieve values of the first example and the records that have just one number won't appear.

if i use `LIKE %4%` SQL will retrieve `4, 45, 47`

if i use REGEX `'^4$'` SQL only will retrieve `4` from both examples...

Any help?

P.S: Sorry my english I'm from Brazil!

Comment: Are you trying to select numbers in a certain range (<4), or numbers containing certain digits (regex ^4.*) which is all numbers beginning with 4?

Comment: Rouben I'm trying to select certain rows with certain digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *I have a column on my table that stores values like `1,3,45,32,47,4,9,100,23,2`*
2. *I want to make a select and retrieve just the values that match for example `4`*.

Change your where clause like the following:

```
where column_name like '4' or column_name like '4,%' or column_name like '%,4,%'
```

and it should be working.

Comment: I can't up-vote yet. I need 15 reputation for that. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the = operator in the where clause

```
Select some-col 
from some_table 
where column_name = '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Store values as : ,1,3,45,32,47,4,9,100,23,2,

And then do SQL LIKE %,4,%

Comment: Yeah. I thing I should do this

Answer (score 0):

```
where find_in_set('4', col_name)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

ps- think about changing your database design so that you dont need to use these hacks to query your database.